# ¿Cómo cambiar el layout de devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Estoy usando `devise` en una `app rails` para el manejo de sesiones, y quería saber si se podía cambiar el `layout` en el cual se muestran los formularios ya que por defecto utiliza `application.html.erb`.

Estuve analizando la documentación de [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) donde se explica cómo definir un layout específico en un controlador pero no tengo acceso al controlador de `devise` en la carpeta de mi app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La solución más simple es crear un `layout` llamado `devise.html.erb` en el directorio `/app/views/layouts/`, y rails va a tomar ese `layout` para aplicarlos a las vistas devise.

En otras palabras, crea un archivo:

```
/app/views/layouts/devise.html.erb
```

Y coloca el en el `layout` que deseas aplicar a las vistas `devise`.

Answer (score 1):

Devise tiene un generador justo para esto.

Generador de vistas: `$ rails generate devise:views`
Generador de Controladores: `$ rails generate devise:controllers [scope]`

Puedes ver más detalles aquí: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views